# Angular:: mat-table - Unresolved variable

Tags: angular, mat-table

I'm getting Unresolved variable stationId and Unresolved variable street exceptions + the table is completely empty (even without the head). The console doesn't have any errors. The request to data server was successful.

Table html:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="stations" class="mat-elevation-z8">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="stationId">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>stationId</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.stationId}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="operator">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>operator</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.operator}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="city">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>city</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.city}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="address">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>address</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.street}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

Table ts:

```
export class StationsComponent implements OnInit {
  title = "STK";
  stations: MatTableDataSource<StationsInterface>;
  paginator: MatPaginator;
  displayedColumns: ["stationId", "operator", "city", "address"];

  constructor(@Inject("StationsAPIService") private stationService: StationsAPIService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.stationService.getStations().subscribe(stations => {
      this.stations = new MatTableDataSource(stations);
      this.stations.paginator = this.paginator;
      console.log(stations);
    });
  }

}
```

Station Interface:

```
export interface StationsInterface {
  stationId: number;
  scopeOfApproval: string;
  postalCode: string;
  city: string;
  street: string;
  operator: string;
  telephoneNumber: string;
  email: string;
  community: string;
  district: string;
  region: string;
}
```

When I use the same dataSource without mat-table and ng-containers, the rows are rendering just fine. 
Can anyone help me fix it please? Thank you in advance.

Upd.:
I'm also getting this error when trying to renderRows():

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'dataSource: [object Object]'. Current value: 'dataSource: undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because your `displayedColumns` is undefined

Try

```
displayedColumns = ["stationId", "operator", "city", "address"];
```

instead of

```
displayedColumns: ["stationId", "operator", "city", "address"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `async` pipe:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="stations$ | async" class="mat-elevation-z8">
```

```
export class StationsComponent {
  title = "STK";
  stations: MatTableDataSource<StationsInterface>;
  paginator: MatPaginator;
  displayedColumns: ["stationId", "operator", "city", "address"];

  readonly stations$ = this.stationService.getStations().pipe(
    map((stations) => {
      const source =  new MatTableDataSource(stations);
      source.paginator = this.paginator;
    }),
    shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: 0 })
  );

  constructor(@Inject("StationsAPIService") private stationService: StationsAPIService) {
  }
}
```

I'm missing the `paginator` in the template though, are you sure it's there?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Nothing has changed though, the variables are still unresolved and the table is empty :(